# Copy Mac Server LDAP contents to OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, mac, openldap

Is it possible to copy all content from a Mac LDAP server (which is proprietary modified OpenLDAP). Doesn't matter if I have to do it by replication (which I think is even harder) or copying the datastore from the Mac to the linux box running OpenLDAP.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not entirely possible: What you will be missing are passwords, as MacOS stores these in a special, separate database and you can't export it.

Other than that, it should not be a big problem, you just have to make sure to have the correct schemas included on the new OpenLDAP server (can be found in `/etc/openldap` on the Mac) and then export the data as LDIF file from one server and import it on the other.

You should just make sure the target server has no records already defined to avoid any collisions.